# Convert string number to integer number

Tags: java

I have "1" as a string, and I would like to convert it to decimal, `1`, as integer.

I tried `charAt()`, but it returns 49, not 1 integer.

So, what is required to convert the "1" string to 1 integer?

Comment: Did you see String API?

Comment: `49` is the numerical equivalent for the character `1`. To get the numerical value of a single character, you can do this: `c - '0'`. So, `'1' - '0' = 1`.

Comment: @Obicere - Yep, while that's almost certainly not what the OP wanted, it's worthwhile to point it out.  An important step in understanding the difference between a (conceptual) number and it's physical representation.

Comment: @HotLicks it will be extremely useful if he wishes to create his own method for parsing it.

Comment: @Obicere - Yes, especially if his instructor assigns him the task of writing a number parser from scratch.  (And it seems to be a popular assignment, and one that many folks break their pick on.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Use Wrapper Class.**

*Examples are below*

**int**

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("1"); // Outputs 1
```

**float**

```
float a = Float.parseFloat("1"); // Outputs 1.0
```

**double**

```
double a = Double.parseDouble("1"); // Outputs 1.0
```

**long**

```
long a = Long.parseLong("1"); // Outputs 1
```

Comment: Or Float, or Double, depending on the type of data.

Answer (score 8):

```
int one = Integer.parseInt("1");
```

Ideally you should be catching errors too:

```
int i;
String s = "might not be a number";
try {
   i = Integer.parseInt(s);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) does exactly that.

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1");
//foo now equals 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "1";
int i = Integer.valueOf(s);
```